# Flux - How to deal with multiple stores updating the same view?

Tags: facebook, react-native, flux

I'm a beginner to the flux model but I think I understand it at a high level:

event creator -> events -> dispatch -> store -> view and around we go!

Given that the flux model supports multiple stores, if you have say an event loop that dispatches to 2+ stores, that in turn updates the same view.

How do you manage any inadvertent flicker that would come from that process?

I haven't quite enabled/used react yet (I assume a catch all answer will be that react handles this heavy lifting part of reducing this) but conceptually how could this work outside a specific implementation.

Since store changes are applied serially across stores, do you just wait until all the stores are down processing the dispatcher, and then allow them individually to fire all their changes? Even then you still would loop through and dispatch events at the end, and you'd still potentially have overlapping updates to the UI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have different options here:

**The vanilla solution** is to utilize a `waitFor()` function in your store-structure, and ensure that in the end each component has only one store it listens to. More or less like this:
[image: Store waiting for other stores]

Caveat is that your action types and store structures need to be in sync: Each action needs to communicate to *all* stores that are included in a waitFor cycle.  The example in the picture will fail to trigger a render. The top-most store is not listening to the action from dispatcher, and the right store will keep waiting for update. Also, the red line may cause a similar dead end, if it is only 1 of the components. My way of dealing with this is: make all stores in the first line listen to ALL actions, and if the action is irrelevant: emit change.

The other option is to **consolidate your data into a single store**.
This does not make the issue go away: you need to handle the dependency issues inside the single store. But it does take away the hassle of many actions, many waitFors, and many change emissions..

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the action is processed synchronously - all stores will have emitted, the controller views with have called setState, etc. before the stack unwinds and browser gets a chance to re-render the DOM, so flicker is not possible (the browser won't render in the middle of a function running, since otherwise all DOM manipulation code would cause random flickering).

However, as you say, there will potentially be multiple stores emitting changes, and multiple components listen to them, and hence you may end up calling 'setState' multiple times (even on the same component). This sounds inefficient, but under most circumstances it isn't. As long as the current action originated from an event that came from React (e.g. an event handler added to a component in the JSX), React automatically batches all calls to setState and only does the re-render to the DOM (i.e. any required DOM updates) once, immediately (and synchronously) after you have finished processing the event.

There is a case to be aware of - if you dispatch an action from something outside of a React event handler (e.g. a promise.then, an AJAX callback, setTimeout callback, etc.) then React will have to re-render for every single call to setState in that function, since it doesn't know when else to do it. You can avoid this by using the undocumented batched rendering feature (0.14, note that 0.13 had a different API for this):

```
ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(myFunctionThatDispatchesActions);
```

An alternative might be to use an off-the-shelf Flux implementation which does this for you already. See e.g. https://github.com/acdlite/redux-batched-updates